# how to remove css display attribute by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSS id #cross-reference-section-value set to `display: none`. It hides the label field in the HTML. I have JavaScript code to select the value and store it into the the hidden element like this:

```
var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
      $("#cross-reference-section-value").text(id + " " + to_s);
      $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");
  };
```

Now I want to enable or remove that attribute of `display: none` using JavaScript to make it visible to display the value. And one more thing is I have selected the id and string value. Is it possible to display only the string not the id? But the id should be hidden. Because I am calculating the other fields through this id. So, I just want to hide this id and show the string. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _string_? Do you mean `$('#'+id).text(to_s).show()`? When a parent is hidden it's children are hidden too.

Comment: the harder I try, the less I understand what you want to accomplish here, sorry

Comment: if you want to display `to_s` but not `id` you should put them in different `<span>` elements. Then you can hide one span and show the other.

Comment: I am new to this forum and ROR. So, Please remove your downvotes for me please. I really appreciate your helps. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$("#cross-reference-section-value").show()` or something like `$("#cross-reference-section-value").css('display', 'block')`.

I don't think you can just show the string though, seems like this is extra logic that needs to be added in the js code.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use jquery by the syntax
$('#elementID').attr('display','block');

Answer (score 1):

To remove display: none you want to create a class called 'hide' which contains the display: none attribute, so remove the attribute from the id and into the new class. Then you can remove the class when you want to show it.

```
$('#cross-reference-section-value').removeClass('hide');
```

That will show both the id and string, but if you want to show one but hide the other, you'll need to put them in separate elements inside the main element, so you can target one but not the other.

Comment: How is this better than just `.show()`?